# How to reset the download when the GetIt package manager fails?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, delphi-10-seattle

I tried to download the OmniThread lib via GetIt when Delphi crashed.
*Other packages downloaded, compiled and installed just fine, so I guess it's a once off.*

Now GetIt refuses to install OmniThread, because it sees the partial download, assumes all is well and starts compiling. 
This breaks with a compile error and GetIt does not allow me to reset the state and clean up the download.

**Where does GetIt store its downloads and how do I clean this out, so that GetIt will redownload the source from scratch?**

Comment: filed: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-12387

Comment: GetIt installs files to {My Documents}\Embarcadero\Studio\<version>\CatalogRepository. Maybe you can try clearing the OmniThreadLibrary subfolder.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Luis Navarro from Embacadero just explained to me:

> Close the IDE, then delete the OmniThread folder from `MyDocuments\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\CatalogRepository`
>   After that, you have to edit the registry and delete also the Omnithread folder from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\17.0\CatalogRepository\Elements`

This worked like a charm.
Note that for me there was no registry key in the above path for OmniThread yet. Perhaps the key only gets written upon successful installation of the package.
In that case you only need to delete the `PackageName` directory and reinstall.

Comment: Works for Konopka Radiant Shapes too.

Comment: Works for both Jedi packages too (jcl and jvcl). I had to install JCL first, but I did JVCL first. The JVCL installer exited with an error and after that, I could not uninstall JVCL with the GetIt Manager. So thanks to this solution I could 'uninstall' both packages and install it again in the correct order.

This should be the accepted answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

People should also note the screenshot below regarding Patches installed via GetIt. Patches don't seem to be listed under Elements, but under CatalogRepository

[image]